# How to import hive tables from Hadoop datalake to AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, impala

I need suggestions on importing data from Hadoop datalake (Kerberos authenticated) to AWS. All the tables in the Hive table should land in s3 and then needs to be loaded to AWS RDS.
I have considered the following options:
1) AWS Glue ?
2) Spark connecting to hive metastore ?
3) Connecting to impala from AWS ?

There are around 50 tables to be imported. How can i maintain the schema ? IS it better to import the data and then create a seperate schema in RDS ?

Comment: You can just backup the metastore and import to RDS or Glue... The main issue here is the actual table locations in S3

Comment: @cricket_007, I need to import only a few tables from remote Hive to AWS. So do you think that backing up the hive metastore to glue catalogue would be a good option ?

Comment: If you do back it up, you need to ensure the Hive metastore version matches. And I'm not even sure if importing back into Glue makes sense because the actual table file locations will not be the same.

Comment: For my curiosity, why do you decide to move data from Hive to RDS? And that must lands on S3 first?

Comment: @wyc The data was on the Hadoop cluster and I wanted to move to S3 for analysis. It was a specific requirement, my client wanted data in S3 and later loaded to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would dump a list of all tables needing moved.

From that, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` over them all, and save the queries.

Run distcp, or however else you want to move the data into S3 / EBS

Edit each create table command to specify a Hive table location that's in the cloud data store. I believe you'll need to make all these as external tables since you cannot put data directly into the Hive warehouse directory and have the metastore immediately know of it.

Run all the commands on the AWS Hive connection.

I have coworkers who have used [CircusTrain](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/circus-train)

Impala and Spark are meant for processing. You're going to need to deal mostly with the Hive metastore here.